# Difference in behavior of `<Esc>` and `inoremap jk <Esc>` in vim

Tags: ubuntu, vim

I just installed Ubuntu 12.04 on a new computer and `apt-get install[ed] vim` and I'm having some weird behavior with my aliased <kbd>Esc</kbd> - if I'm in `INSERT` mode and I type the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key, I exit `INSERT` mode and the cursor moves one character to the left, as expected, but if I type the `jk` alias, which I have defined in my `.vimrc` as `inoremap jk <Esc>`, I exit `INSERT` mode and the cursor moves one character to the *right*, which is actually quite disconcerting. Any ideas as to why this is the case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think this is because of this rule alone, something else is causing this. If I create a `.vimrc` file with just this rule in it:

```
$ more .vimrc
inoremap jk <Esc>
```

I get the same behavior as expected from both methods.

#### Example #1 - <kbd>esc</kbd>

Invoke `vim`, go into *Insert* mode, right arrow 1 time, hit <kbd>Esc</kbd>.

[image: ss of vim w/ esc]

#### Example #2 - <kbd>jk</kbd>

Invoke `vim`, go into *Insert* mode, right arrow 1 time, hit <kbd>jk</kbd>.

[image: ss of vim w/ jk]

Answer (score 2):

The answer was derived from slm's answer, which is that it wasn't the rule alone which caused this issue; my rule, in *full*, was actually

```
inoremap jk <Esc>  " Recommended in http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/10.html
```

It hadn't caused a problem on the Vim implementations I was using on Mac OS and Debian for some reason, but the two extra space characters after the <kbd>Esc</kbd> in the rule, before the comment were causing the cursor to move forward two spaces after exiting `INSERT` mode.